# Gerrit submission has conflict

Tags: gerrit

Why there is a conflict when I submit a change into a branch on Gerrit, but when I rebase my change onto that branch locally, git can do a fast forward rebase and without any conflict?

The behavior of Gerrit submission is not like git's merge. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerrit is very conservative with merges/rebasing.  If a file has been modified by your commit has also been modified in the branch you are trying to merge with, Gerrit will fail with a conflict even if git is capable of resolving the conflict automatically.  This is just to be extra safe.

In newer versions of Gerrit there is a configuration to turn this safety check off, and have Gerrit trust git's automerge results.

Comment: The configuration option is per project and documented in the last sentence of this paragraph: https://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.2.2/project-setup.html#submit_type